# Scrum Template for TFS 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2010, team-explorer, tfs-2005

**What I have?**

I have TFS 2005 installed on Windows Server 2003. I have another machine having Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7. So, I have Visual Studio Team Explorer 2010.

**What I need?**

I need to create a TFS project with Scrum Template.

**What problem am I facing?**

I tried [Process Template Version 1](http://www.scrumforteamsystem.co.uk/version-1/process-template) from Scrum for Team System site I did not work. I also tried [Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 1.0](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ac03e3-df99-4776-be39-1917cbfc5d8e/) with no luck.

Can anyone tell me if there is any suitable Scrum Template for my environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download a VSTS 2005 compatible SCRUM template at http://vstsscrum.codeplex.com/.